# How to solve NoReverseMatch, no arguments not found? (Django)

Tags: python, django

Edit: I was able to achieve the desired behavior, by modifying view.py as follows

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:entry>", views.entry, name="entry"),
    path("edit/<str:page>", views.edit, name="edit"),
    path("new", views.new, name="new"),
    path("edit/CSS", views.edit, name="edit")
]
```

But **I do not know, why this works!**!!??? Notice: It does not only work for the entry 'CSS', but also for the other entries.

Template edit.html

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Edit
{% endblock %}
    
{% block body %}
    <form action="{% url 'edit' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table border="1">
            {{ form_newpage }}
        </table>
        <button type="submit">Save Page</button>
    </form>
    
{% endblock %}
```

---

I am new to Django. I get the following Error: `NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'edit' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit/(?P<page>[^/]+)$']`

To specify: I am building a wikipedia-like website and now want to allow the feature of editing. Therefore I included

```
path("edit/<str:page>", views.edit, name="edit"),
```

into my urlpatterns at urls.py in my encyclopedia app.

For edit, views.py looks like this:

```
def edit(request, page):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {
        "form_newpage": NewPageForm(initial={'content': util.get_entry(page), 'title': page}),
        "form_searchwiki": SearchWikiForm()
    })
```

When I now try to access http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit/CSS - CSS being a valid entry of that encyclopedia - I get the NoReverseMatch Error. In the Traceback the valuefor the local variable page is 'CSS', so I do not understand, why Django does not recognize 'CSS' as a proper argument in the url.

get_entry function:

```
 def get_entry(title):
        """
        Retrieves an encyclopedia entry by its title. If no such
        entry exists, the function returns None.
        """
        try:
            f = default_storage.open(f"entries/{title}.md")
            return f.read().decode("utf-8")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            return None
```

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/fed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/fed/cs/cs50_web/wiki/encyclopedia/views.py", line 59, in edit
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {
  File "/home/fed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/home/fed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/home/fed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/fed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/fed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/fed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/fed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/fed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/fed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/fed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/fed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/fed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/fed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/fed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/fed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 446, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "/home/fed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/fed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'edit' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit/(?P<page>[^/]+)$']
[22/Dec/2020 17:20:16] "GET /edit/CSS HTTP/1.1" 500 153425
```

What I have tried now (inside the edit function in views.py) is:

```
return HttpResponse("Hello, world!")
```

.. this works without errors.

I think, from what I have read by now, that the error has to be in urls.py?! The Error is basically saying that there was not match for edit/CSS, when there should be a match..?!

Comment: Can we see your `get_entry` function?

Comment: Yes, I added the code. However this should not be the error, I think.

Comment: Show us the full error traceback from the **console** as text.

Comment: The failed `reverse` is coming from a template tag. Post the code in your template; probably your implementation of the `{% url %}` tag is causing the problem. Does your implementation of the url tag in `encyclopedia/edit.html` pass the `page` arg? Note that the problem is *not* in your urls.py because your view actually renders properly; on that, see the third line of your traceback or ask me for clarification.)

Comment: Ok, I included the template code. I know that {% url 'edit' %} is "false", but somehow it works now in combination with the last path in urls.py, that I added. And if I substitute {% url 'edit' page %}there is the NoReverseMatch error once again.

Comment: Ok, I got a satisfying solution now. I substituted {% url 'edit' page %} and had to pass into the render function "page": page. Thank You! However, I am still wondering why the other "solution" with the random edit/CSS path also worked?:/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you do not pass page in your context but you name it title so page has no value in your url template tag

```
return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {
        "form_newpage": NewPageForm(initial={'content': util.get_entry(page), 'title': page}),
        "form_searchwiki": SearchWikiForm()
    })
```